# in c++ my operator overloading prefix not work

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

**Question has been modified**

I have a list class (like linking list) that contain `add()` and `begin()` functions
`add()` function that adds to tail
`begin()` function that returns the address of the first element (head)

i try to make  my class support for-range `for(:)` so i try to implementation `begin()`, `end()` and `operator++()` functions, But I got stuck on `operator++()` it doesn't work **(read the note below)**

**New Addition**

the problem is that the `i` is a Node Pointer so I can't do this `++i` that will just increase the address of the pointer and it will not run the `operator++()` because it is a Node Pointer not an Object from Node struct so when i do this `++(*i)` it will run the `operator++()`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class List
{
    struct Node
    {
        int info;
        Node *next;
        Node(int val) : info(val), next(NULL) {}
        
       Node * operator++(){ // not working
            cout << "i am alive\n";
            *this = *this->next;
            return this;
        }
    };
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;

public:
    void add(int val) // add to tail, O(1)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node(val);

        if (!head)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            return;
        }

        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    Node *begin()
    {
        return head;
    }
};
int main()
{
    List l;
    l.add(2);
    l.add(5);
    l.add(10);
        
    auto i = l.begin(); // *i is 2
    ++i; 
    cout << (*i).info; // output is 0
}
```

**NOTE THAT:**
if i do that, it will work and print 5

```cpp
    auto i = l.begin(); // *i is 2
    i->operator++(); // will work
    // ++(*i); //also will work
    cout << (*i).info; // output is 5
```

Comment: try to replace `auto` with the actual type. It doesn't help here

Comment: `operator++` is a member function of the `Node` class. `i` is a `Node*` pointer. You're changing the function call--the equivalent of `++i` is `i.operator++()`, but you call `i->operator++()`. But beyond that, `operator++` in your `Node` class doesn't change the `Node` it's called on and it returns a `Node*` pointer, not a `Node`.

Comment: You probably want to make an iterator class and use operator++ on the iterator.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, that solve the problem (remove the `auto` and replace it with `Node*` , but that sove the problem **only** i move the Node class outside List Class.

Comment: no it doesnt *solve* the problem, it just makes it more visible

Comment: yeah, i don't want it like this anyway, i want to make the Node class inside, and i want it interacts with `auto` keyword

i will put your note in the question

Comment: sorry, you misunderstood. Replacing `auto` with `Node*` does not change anything about the code. I was hoping that it is a good hint, or make it easier to see what is the issue

Comment: after a lot of tests and shouting, I understood the problem, 
the `i` is a Node Pointer so I can't do this `++i` that will just increase the address of thr pointer
and it will not run the `operator++()` because it is a Node Pointer not an Object from Node stract

so when i do this `++(*i)` it will not the `operator++()`

Comment: @Nathan Pierson thanks, i understood the problem now, and trying to solve it now

Comment: @drescherjm I don't want to use libs or anything external

Comment: You can create your own iterator class. I don't really see this working without it however I may be wrong. I have not written code like this in 2 over decades.

Comment: writing your own iterator `!=` using external libs. You seem to want to have your custom iterator, so you should write one. Using `Node*` won't work and `Node` wont work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, I solved the problem by implementing the Iterator Class by myself like what you said

my class is now support for range `for(:)`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class List
{
    struct Node
    {
        int info;
        Node * next;
        Node(int val): info(val), next(NULL) {}
    };

    class Iterator
    {
        Node * ptr;
    public:
        Iterator(Node *p): ptr(p) {}

        Iterator & operator=(Node * Np)
        {
            ptr = Np;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator!=(Iterator & it)
        {
            return this->ptr != it.ptr;
        }

        Iterator &operator++()
        {
            if (ptr)
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
                return * this;
            }
        }

        Iterator &operator++(int)
        {
            Iterator it = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return it;
        }

        int operator*()
        {
            return ptr->info;
        }
    };

    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;

public:
    void add(int val)   // add to tail, O(1)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node(val);

        if (!head)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            return;
        }

        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }

    Iterator begin()
    {
        return Iterator(head);
    }

    Iterator end()
    {
        return Iterator(NULL);
    }
};
int main()
{
    List l;
    l.add(2);
    l.add(5);
    l.add(10);

    auto i = l.begin();
    ++i;
    cout << *i <<'\n'; // output 5
    
    for(auto it : l){
        cout << it <<' '; // output 2 5 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation approach to the increment operator is wrong. It is not supposed to return the incremented value. Instead, it should increment the value of the object it is called on. Then, it should return a reference to that object for the prefix variant or a copy of the former value in the postfix variant.

The problem with your code is also that it compares apples to oranges. Your `i` is a pointer and `++i` will just increment that pointer. It doesn't care whether your class implements an increment operator. In order to invoke that, you need `++*i`.

Comment: your i right when i do this `++(*i); ` it works, 

how i can improve the code to work with `++i`
can you write the code to understand it fine

Comment: Just look at the C++ standard library code. There is also a lib in Boost to facilitate iterator coding. As a hint: Your iterator contains just a pointer and moves that pointer between the elements.

Comment: look i don't want to use libs or anything external
i try to handle for range in my class 
to do that i should make a `begin()`, `end()` and `operator++()` functions

Comment: Yes, and what better to learn from than existing high-class code from the C++ standard library or Boost?

Comment: i understand your point, I can learn and understand the implementation, and do it in my class, i will try that

Answer (score -1):

You can easily implement a `const` iterator-like object as below, using `Node`. If you want to be able to modify the list through the iterator, however, you might have to create a new class.

```
Node &operator++(){
    return *this = *this->next;
}

int operator*() {
  return this->info;
}

Node cbegin() {
  return *head;
}
```

Comment: This still has the problem that writing an `operator++` that could be `const` is pretty unexpected.

Comment: not sure, but I think OP wants to write `++i;` to have an effect on `i`. With your changes OPs main is still wrong

Comment: There is no `const` in your suggested operator.

Comment: But ultimately this all is just foregrounding the issue that a `Node` and an iterator aren't _really_ the same thing, because now calling `operator++` to try to move around the list will actually be rearranging the contents of the list. An actual iterator class that acts like a `Node*` pointer but with correct increment and decrement behavior is what's called for.

Comment: @NathanPierson. I don't see how this would be rearranging the list. I agree though `Node` doesn't really fit too well with the properties of iterator. It was an attempt to solve OP's problem without introducing new classes. Also this will segfault when it reaches `cend()` haha

Comment: It's a tradeoff. Right now, it doesn't rearrange the list because `cbegin` returns a copy of the head node, so when you do `Node head = someList.cbegin(); ++head;` it doesn't rearrange `someList`. But you shouldn't need to make a copy of every node just to iterate over a list without changing anything.

Comment: To show what I mean about the rearranging, imagine what happens if we use `begin` instead of `cbegin`. Would `begin` return a reference to the head node? `Node head = someList.begin(); head.info = 7;` compiles, great. But `Node head = someList.begin(); ++head;` will mean that `someList`'s head has become a copy of the second node. It's like we've dropped the head, but without even freeing up the associated memory.

Comment: @NathanPierson The idea is that it's only 4 or 8 more bytes (12 or 16 vs 8), so that shouldn't be a big deal. But yes, things get problematic when we start modifying things with the iterators. `++head` and `*head` for read should work ok though.

Comment: *Iterator* is a recognized design pattern. Please just don't call anything around that somehow "resembles" an iterator by this name, it may be simply misleading for new comers because it has been quite a strict concept in the software engineering. Not that I have anything against your proposal :)